# Rails5 Category with Parent Category Id on the same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, ruby-on-rails-5

Ok so what I have been doing for categories is I have had 2 tables Categories(id, name) and SubCategories(id, name, category_id) that are related through the models. I set inverse_of as you will see below. 
My question is when I use to code in PHP years ago we use to have one table "Categories" and it had id, name, parent_id(0 by default) we then used that one table to control the outputs of navigations, breadcrumbs, and other navigational elements.

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateSubCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :sub_categories do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :category_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sub_categories, inverse_of: :category
end
class SubCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :categories, inverse_of: :sub_category
end
```

I have been programming in Ruby on Rails now for over 4 years and I have yet to find a real nice "Rubyway" to achieve this. Over the years I have seen examples of using what I am already using with the 2 table method, however this does not seem very intuitive because when the system gets many categories and sub categories like 100's the page load time will be impacted in processing. Is anyone useing or know of a one table method like

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]   def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :parent_id
      t.timestamps
    end   
  end 
end
```

The problem I have always had is the model and how to get the system to realize that a record can belong to a record on the same table. I have been able to achieve it manually but I have not found a way to set it up where formtastic and other gems like rails admin would play nice with it.

Comment: What is the reason for the down vote? Any down votes should include a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you're looking for a tree structure. [acts_as_tree](https://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree) has been around for some time. If you're using PostgreSQL, the `ltree` extension may be of interest as well (along with the [pg_ltree](https://github.com/sjke/pg_ltree) gem).

Comment: Yea tree structure is something else that I have always come across however it still does not solve the problem in a clean fashion. IMO it only serves to be an over complicated solution that should be relatively simple. I am looking at looping through the records and building an array and organizing based off of the parent id and nesting where appropriate. In PHP and other web languages you just do a nested loop 3 deep to output the results, however in ruby it has never seemed that simple with activerecord.

Comment: Knowing what I know about ruby there should be a more elegant way to approach this programmatically.

Comment: If you are using PostgreSQL then yes this is a actually not too bad of a solution, however MySQL it does nothing for. However once I solve this I am going to post the answer because it is a question I have seen asked a lot over the years and I think its time there was a viable answer.

Comment: Use of PostgreSQL + ltree isn't the only option offered here. `acts_as_tree` uses a simple string column and ruby code to do the rest, which is DB agnostic.